# How to send data from adapter to activity and display it in a recyclerview?

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview

I try to pass data from an adapter to an activity and display it in a recyclerview. I am getting the NullPointerException when I run the app. What am I doing wrong?

*This is the activity where I want to display data*:

```
public class ListOfChatsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Toolbar lToolbar;
RecyclerView lRV;
BottomNavigationView lBnv;
ListOfChatsAdapter adapter;
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager;
ArrayList<String> chatList;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_of_chats);

    lToolbar = findViewById(R.id.lToolbar);
    lRV = findViewById(R.id.lRV);
    lBnv = findViewById(R.id.lBnv);
    Intent intent = this.getIntent();
    if(intent!=null){
    String string = intent.getStringExtra("username");
    chatList.add(string);}

    adapter = new ListOfChatsAdapter(chatList, getApplicationContext());
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    lRV.setAdapter(adapter);
    lRV.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
}
```

*This is the adapter from where I want to send data:*

```
public class SearchAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SearchAdapter.ViewHolder> {

ArrayList<User> friendsSearchedList = new ArrayList<>();
Context mContext;

public SearchAdapter(ArrayList<User> friendsSearchedList, Context mContext){
    this.friendsSearchedList = friendsSearchedList;
    this.mContext = mContext;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.search_user_item,
            parent, false);
    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(view);
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final User username = friendsSearchedList.get(position);
    holder.text.setText(username.getUsername());
   holder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String iUsername = holder.text.getText().toString();
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.putExtra("username", iUsername);
        }
    });

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return friendsSearchedList == null ? 0:friendsSearchedList.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView text;
    Button button;
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
    public ViewHolder(View itemView){
        super(itemView);

        text = itemView.findViewById(R.id.sText);
        button = itemView.findViewById(R.id.addFriend);
        relativeLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
    }
}
```

}

I don't open the Activity from this Adapter. I just want to send extras. I tried more options, but I don't get it right.

Comment: Do you open the `Activity` from `Adapter` or only send some extras ?

Comment: Only send extras

Comment: See for changes in the answer.

Comment: which class and methods contain each of the code snippets that you provide? Please show this in the code by surrounding the snippets with the appropriate class and method declarations.

Comment: Can you share the error stack trace?

Comment: I added the classes and methods

Answer (score 0):

> Change 1

`adapter = new ListOfChatsAdapter(chatList, getApplicationContext());`

Why is the `ListOfChatsAdapter` being used here? You have included SearchAdapter as the adapter to use in the RecyclerView.

> Change 2

The ViewHolder object that is returned by `onCreateViewHolder()`, should be of type `SearchAdapter.ViewHolder` and not just `ViewHolder`. The same applies to the first arguement of `onBindViewHolder()`.

Try these and check